# Time series split in python taking into account different products

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, cross-validation

I have df (pandas) containing temporal data for several products (see below). The products may not start or finish in the same date as the others (eg. prod 1 and 2 series finished before dn, while prod 4 started somewhere between d3 and dn). I want to do a time series split, taking into account each produt. By doing that, I can have the same date on training and test, depending on the product. How do I do that?

```
date  prod  value
d1    p1    10
d1    p2    10
d2    p1    15
d2    p2    12
d3    p1    8
d3    p2    5
d3    p3    7
.
dn    p2    20
dn    p4    10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use:

```
d = {prod: group.set_index('date')['value'] for prod, group in df.groupby('prod')}
```

if you want all products have the same index:

```
d = {prod: group.set_index('date')['value'].reindex(df['date'].unique()) 
     for prod, group in df.groupby('prod')}
```